# How to show all databases in mongoshell?

Tags: mongodb

I apologize if this is easily google-able or already asked before.

I have tried googling, but I get hits to explain how to get all collections.

I am using MongoDB 2.4.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `show databases` or `show dbs` in the Mongo shell:

```
$ mongo                                                     
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8                                                    
connecting to: test                                                             
> show databases                                                                
db1     0.203125GB                                                              
local   0.078125GB                                                              
test    0.203125GB
```

This will list your databases.

> To list the available databases, use the helper **`show dbs`**. See also How can I access different databases temporarily? to access a different database from the current database without switching your current database context (i.e. db..) [source](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/)